# how to deploy portion of my site only

Tags: msdeploy

I have a following set of files/folders that I need to deploy to my web site

+---App_Browsers 
+---bin 
+---Config 
+---Development 
+---static 
+---xsl 
web.config 
404.html 
500.html

I would like to sync the files/folder with the one of the server and I don't want to erase any other file, folder on the server.
Ideally I would use 
**msdeploy -verb:sync**, 
because I want the folder that I'm deploying to be synchronized, but I want to preserve the existing folders on the site. **-skip** is not an option too, because the existing folders are dynamic, we have CMS system that might be changing files/folders on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete answer, but try -enableRule:DoNotDeleteRule:

```
msdeploy -verb:sync -source:package=package.zip -dest:auto -enableRule:DoNotDeleteRule
```

Comment: Right, I have tried that before, but it is not the perfect solution for me, because it doesn't synchronize the folders that I'm deploying. Since it doesn't delete, it leaves files that are no longer in my package.

Comment: If this were my CMS application (and if I had to use the file system instead of a database for content storage), then I would use virtual directories for content storage. I'd probably also put all of the content under a `/content` folder and tell MSDEPLOY to ignore it.

Comment: I love your idea, it totally makes sense and it will make my life way easier, however we do have 25+ web sites like that plus we have DEV, QA, PTE, STAGE and PROD environments and that change will generate lots of work for our Deployment team with no business value, so I'm pretty sure what the answer of my management will be. BTW I wanted to vote "up"  to your answer, but I cannot unfortunately. The system doesn't allow me yet.

Comment: The business value is the ability to deploy easily, as well as imho making it easier to reason about your site. It's much simpler to think "everything under /content is content, and everything not under /content is not" than to have to think of all the random folders which may or may not happen to contain content.